Salesforce API - Query of Change Data Capture's Selected Entities jsforce
Issue
I am trying to make a query to the Salesforce API to retrieve the "Selected Entities" that are listed under "Change Data Capture" using jsforce v1.11.1.  The goal would be to query and pull a dynamic list of all Selected Entities in Change Data Capture from Salesforce.
When I make this SOQL query directly through the the Developer Console it retrieves all of the desired information.
SELECT Id,DeveloperName,EventChannel,SelectedEntity FROM PlatformEventChannelMember

Then when I run this same query using jsforce I get an error saying:

INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'PlatformEventChannelMember' is not supported.

const res = await conn.tooling.query('SELECT Id,DeveloperName,EventChannel,SelectedEntity FROM PlatformEventChannelMember') 

What I have tried

Triple checked that I have the correct permissions to make the query.

Tried variations of the query with and with out tooling.
conn.query('SELECT Id,DeveloperName,EventChannel,SelectedEntity FROM PlatformEventChannelMember')


Used different methods to retrieve the data.
conn.tooling.request('/services/data/v61.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember')


Tried the Metadata API.
I am open to any suggestions. Feel like I am close but can't seem to get it.



You're using same org, same user in jsforce and Dev console? Might be something with permissions. Are you able to see what API version jsforce used when running your query? Maybe the object doesn't exist "yet". When all else fails you could try making apex rest service returning this but I guess it's something simple missing

Permissions were one of my first thoughts as well. As far as I can I am logging in with the same user in the browser as in my code (ids match 100% as well). The org id that prints out in the code is 3 characters longer than the one in the Company Information tab of Salesforce but all characters up until that point match. I am still new to SF so I am not sure what that implies entirely. The user that I am using has the same id and name within the org at the same endpoint, so I am assuming for now that the orgs are one and the same. I am really hoping it is just something simple missing.

Yesz the 15- vs 18-char id thing can be ignored. Hm. After you login with jsforce go to setup -> login history and try to see which API version was used? Unless there are some useful logs jsforce can generate. Current API should be around number 61... You're on latest version of the library so probably that's good enough tho, change data capture is about 5 years old I think...

Thank you! I think I see what my problem is. It is using v42 of the api which lead me to look in to my version of jsforce which I SWORE I had the latest version of but upon further inspection I found v3.2.3. Strange since I simply ran an npm install jsforce when first setting up the feature and I could have sworn it said the latest was 1.11.1.  Now I can run the query to PlatformEventChannelMemeber with out issue.  Again, thanks @eyescream for the suggestions!

Congrats! Post as your own answer including where you've found the API version used in the end, I'll happily upvote :) you'll get some fake internet points, the question will drop off the "unanswered" list...

I have found the solution to the issue with some helpful suggestions from @eyescream. By looking in Salesforce->Setup->Login History I was able to see the version of the API being sent to Salesforce, it was v42 while latest is v61. When I reinstalled the correct version of jsforce everything works as expected. jsforce v3.2.3 is using v50.
jsforce had v1.11.1 listed as the latest version on NPM. That was updated to be v3.2.3 yesterday and an npm install jsforce will now give you v3.
